# Creating a multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am aware that javascript does not allow true multidimensional arrays but you can sort of "bodge" one together by having arrays within arrays.

I have 2 questions;

1) Would converting 10 arrays into 1 multidimensional array which has 10 arrays within it improve, damage or have no effect on the performance of the webpage?

2) I am hoping to create an array that has 100 elements, each of these will be an array of 2 elements and finally each of these will be an array of indeterminate length.

I have the following code to create this "multidimensional" array:

```
var RouteArray = new Array(100);
for (var i=0; i <100; i++)
{
RouteArray[i]=new Array(2);
    for (var j=0; j <2; j++)
    {
    RouteArray[i][j] = new Array();
    }
}
```

Is this code sensible? or would you experienced coders be able to suggest a better method?

Also I assume that I could then add to the indeterminate arrays in the multidimensional array described above with the following code:

```
RouteArray[88][0].push(ValueToPush);
```

finally could I then call the value I have just pushed using the following?

```
Var ValueAdded = RouteArray[88][0][0];
```

Thanks in advance for your time, and apologies if this question has been answered elsewhere, I did try to search but either couldn't understand the previous posts or found them to be so unlike my situation that I couldn't apply what they suggested.

John

Comment: This question would probably be more on topic on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: As a general suggestion, make yourself familiar with tools like FireBug or the Safari developer console and the like. You can interactively try out stuff. Or just write a minimal html page and include your example code. Just try stuff.

Comment: Your two good friends are http://jsfiddle.net/ (to play around with code) and http://jsperf.com/ (to compare performance). In this case, I'd be tempted to be as lazy with initializing the arrays as possible.

Comment: @Kendall Ahh, You are right, I am asking for more of a review. Thanks I am not sure how to move this question to the review though!

Comment: @ snies and tjp thankyou for your advice i will look into these websites/software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to contemplate over: http://jsperf.com/arraynew

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Would converting 10 arrays into 1 multidimensional array which has
>   10 arrays within it improve, damage or have no effect on the
>   performance of the webpage?

Almost certainly no performance effect, but it will have a huge effect on your ability to understand the code and write less bugs.

> 2) I am hoping to create an array that has 100 indices, each of these
>   will be filled with an array of 2 indices and finally each of these 2
>   indices will have an array of indeterminate length.

That will work exactly like your example code outlines, and it's a good starting point if you want to get your feet wet. In practice arrays with many dimensions are not always the best data structure to model whatever it is your code works with, mainly because they are not "discoverable": you have to know what each dimension is beforehand.

It's quite possible that there is a better way to structure your data in any one particular scenario, but we 'd have to be talking concretely. In any case, the code you give will work.

Comment: Thankyou for your advice and input Jon. i have just come accross another problem, am i able to call an entire array from the multidimensional array using var ValueAddedArray = RouteArray[88][0];?

Comment: You can do that but be careful - ValueAddedArray will be a reference to RouteArray[88][0] - if you change one, the other will change as well.

Comment: @tjp thankyou again for your responce, I just want to check I understand what you are saying.. If I were to do something like the following: var ValueAddedArray = RouteArray[88][0]; followed by ValueAddedArray[2] = "NewValue"; This will add the value NewValue to both ValueAdded[2] and to RouteArray[88][0][2] at the same time? Also will ValueAddedArray.clear(); empty just the array held in the the RouteArray[88][0] index, or the whole RouteArray?

Comment: @TranquilityEden, exactly. There's no clear() method for arrays, but if you say ValueAddedArray = [], it will clear your RouteArray[88][0] as well.